# Mouse input with Rx - Making a sequence of observables?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'm an Rx newbie trying to figure out how to process mouse gestures with Rx. I found this solution somewhere:

```
var mouseMove = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove");
var lMouseDown = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseDown")
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Left);
var lMouseUp = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseUp")
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Left);
var dragSequence =
    from down in lMouseDown
    from move in mouseMove.StartWith(down).TakeUntil(lMouseUp)
    select move;
dragSequence.ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(e => Trace.WriteLine(e.EventArgs.Location));
```

But multiple independent mouse gestures are all part of the same stream. So I can't use a handler for onCompleted; the sequence is never completed. I'd like to break the stream into a separate sequence for each drag, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
var mouseMove = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove");
var lMouseDown = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseDown")
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Left);
var lMouseUp = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseUp")
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Left);

lMouseDown.SelectMany(start =>
{
    // a new drag event has started, prepare to receive input
    var dragSeq = new List<Point>();
    Action<EventPattern<MouseEventArgs>, bool> onNext = (e, mouseUp) => {
        // This code runs for each mouse move while mouse is down.
        // In my case I want to constantly re-analyze the shape being
        // drawn, so I make a list of points and send it to a method.
        dragSeq.Add(e.EventArgs.Location);
        AnalyzeGesture(dragSeq, mouseUp);
    };

    return mouseMove
        .StartWith(start)
        .TakeUntil(lMouseUp.Do(e => onNext(e, true)))
        .Do(e => onNext(e, false));
})
.Subscribe();
```

How this works is, each time a mouse-down arrives, the `start=>{...}` lambda runs. This lambda returns an observable that uses Do() to process each input. Notice that the lambda itself creates an event stream without subscribing to it, and I am discarding the results of the inner and outer observable, because Do() has already processed the input.

The lambda does not subscribe to the query because the outer Subscribe() has the effect of subscribing to both an individual mouse drag and the whole sequence of them (thanks to SelectMany).

In case the mouse-up point differs from last mouse move, I used `Do()` to capture it. However, it appears that the mouse-up point is always equal to the previous point. So here's a slightly simpler version that ignores the mouse-up point:

```
lMouseDown.SelectMany(start =>
{
    var dragSeq = new List<Point>();
    return mouseMove
        .StartWith(start)
        .TakeUntil(lMouseUp)
        .Do(e => {
            dragSeq.Add(e.EventArgs.Location);
            AnalyzeGesture(dragSeq, false);
        }, () => AnalyzeGesture(dragSeq, true));
})
.Subscribe();
```

Comment: This looks like something that should be possible with the `.Scan` operator: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#Scan

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment here is a way in which you might use the `.Scan` operator

```
Func<List<T>, T, List<T>> AddWithNew = (list, t) =>
{
    var newList = list.ToList(); 
    newList.Add(t);
    return newList;
}

var dragGestures = from start in lMouseDown
                   select mouseMove.StartWith(start)
                       .TakeUntil(lMouseUp)
                       .Scan(new List<Point>(), AddWithNew);

dragGestures.Subscribe(listOfPoints => Console.WriteLine(listOfPoints));
```

The sequence will still be "never-ending" but you will receive increasing lists of points to your `Subscribe` method that are reset back to 1 when a new line begins:

```
[(0,0]                // Mouse down
[(0,0), (1,1)]        // Mouse move
[(0,0), (1,1), (1,0)] // Mouse up
[(6,7)]               // Mouse down again
```

You could also use the `.Window` operator to partition your sequence into a sequence of sequences:

```
var dragSequences = from start in lMouseDown
                    select mouseMove.StartWith(start)
                        .TakeUntil(lMouseUp)
                        .Scan(new List<Point>(), AddWithNew)
                        .Window(() => lMouseUp);

dragSequences.Subscribe(seq =>
{
    seq.Subscribe(list => Analyze(list, false);
    seq.Last().Subscribe(list => Analyze(list, true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
var dragSequences = dragSequence.TakeUntil(lMouseUp)
    .Concat(Observable.Return<MouseEventArgs>(null)) // send a NULL event after a drag completes
    .Repeat(); // then start listening for the next drag gesture

dragSequences.ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(e =>
{
    if (e == null)
    {
        // the previous drag operation has completed.  Take any actions you need
    }
    else
    {
        // drag event.  If the event is for MouseDown then it is the start of a new drag
    }
});
```

Comment: The `dragSequence` in the question never completes, so I don't think it makes sense to `Concat` anything to the end of it. That `Repeat()` method gives me an idea though...

Comment: Ah you are right.  I added a call to `TakeUntil(lMouseUp)`, which will cause the sequence to end when the drag operation completes.  You could remove the `.TakeUntil` call from your definition of `dragSequence` since it would not be needed anymore.